# Каким аргуменетов передавать 1 в onClick Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Есть такая функция

```
const onChangeHandler = (e:React.FormEvent<HTMLAnchorElement>, id:any) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  console.log(id)
}
```

Используется здесь

```
return(
  <li key={index}>
    <a href={"#"} onClick={onChangeHandler(Category.id)} >{Category.name}</a>
  </li>
)
```

Но функция требует еще один аргумент, так как первый идет `React.FormEvent`.

Какой должен быть 1 аргумент в функции `onChangeHandler`?

Comment: не знаю на счеть аргумента но как это у тебя работает?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас же написано, что первым аргументом должно быть событие. В реакте структура немного иная чем в JS но они очень схожи.

```
return(
  <li key={index}>
    <a href={"#"} onClick={(e)=>onChangeHandler(e, Category.id)} >{Category.name}</a>
  </li>
)
```

Вверху код решает Ваш вопрос.

```
const onChangeHandler = (e:React.FormEvent<HTMLAnchorElement>, id:any) => {
  console.log(e);
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(id);
}
```

Можете посмотреть структуру событий Реакт приложения

Так же хочу заметить что метод `preventDefault()` это стандартный метод js. Вы должны знать js для того что бы перейти к другим библиотекам. Так легче будет разбираться в новых библиотеках и в чужом коде. Удачи в изучении))